# Choice of preposition: "across/between/for/in British English and American English"

Tags: prepositions

What prepositions can be used at the bold part of the following sentence?
And what differences in meaning can be made there between the ones?

> The second syllable of "et cetera" is pronounced the same **across/between/for/in/of/to** British English and American English.

Prepositions in English are sometimes very tricky to me. I will appreciate all your answers and comments.

Comment: The second syllable of "et cetera" is pronounced the same ***in*** British English and American English.

Comment: As always, it would help if you could indicate which ones *you* think are correct and why (for example, by analogy to phrasing you have heard or read elsewhere). That way, we don't waste time trying to guess.

Comment: @choster Sorry for lack of specific contexts in the question. I wanted to include every detail, but it was too much and extensive to write and clarify. I thought every preposition I wrote in the question seemed to have some grounds to be right to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only "for" and "in".

Others are possible with variation.
Eg "...across the spectrum of British and American variants of English"

Between is also a range word but tends to be exclusive of the end points - it won't work here.

"To" is more about the receiver. If it was about how sounds are perceived by British/American speakers then "to" would be an appropriate preposition.

Comment: A conjunction "both" helps:  "in both American and British English"

Comment: Thank you for kindly answering, Paul Childs. Thanks to you, I've got to know a lot. But, how about another variation with "across", that is "*...across British and American English*"?

Comment: Across lends itself to a continuous rather than discrete set. Just two doesn't make for much of a continuum. Walking across a street isn't about the curb, but what is between. If you are talking about dialects (there are a plethora of British variants and my variant of Australian English inherets from Mancunian an Cockney) then this can work with across.